Using conditionals within \tl_put_right from latex3 explsyntax
In this question (Wrapping the Tasks Command in a New Environment) a solution was proposed to make tasks compatible with a custom \task function using expl3 syntax.
I am trying to run some conditional operations within the command:
\NewDocumentCommand{\itemJ}{s m O{}}{%
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl 
  { 
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\task*}{\task} #2
    \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #3 
  }
}

And am running into issues doing so. I am aware that the conditionals can be run outside of \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl and then they work fine, e.g.
\NewDocumentCommand{\itemJ}{s m O{}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl 
  { 
    \task* #2
    \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #3 
  }
}{\tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl 
  { 
    \task #2
    \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #3 
  }
}
}

The reason that the first option is highly preferable is that I have a lot of conditionals as such within my actual \itemJ and the code gets very long and with a lot of duplication if the second option is required.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\itemJ}{s m O{}}{%
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl 
  { 
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\task*}{\task} #2
    \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #3 
  }
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{harrytasks}
  {
    O{} % optional options
    D(){1} % number of columns
  }
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
  {
    \harry_task_make:nnV {#1} {#2} \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \harry_task_make:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \begin{tasks}[#1](#2) #3 \end{tasks}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \harry_task_make:nnn {nnV}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\title{Tasks Package Example with \texttt{NewDocumentCommand}}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section*{Example Task Lists}

\begin{harrytasks}
  \itemJ{First item}[This is the solution]
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}(2)
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}[label=\alph*., label-format={\bfseries}](2)
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\end{document}

Current output:


You're putting \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\task*}{\task} in the token list and #1 will be evaluated at call time, not at setting time.
\IfBooleanTF{#1}
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \task* #2 \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #3 }
 }
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \task #2 \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #3 }
 }

You might do it in one instruction
\tl_put_right:Ne \l_tmpa_tl
 {
  \exp_not:N \task \IfBooleanT{#1}{*} \exp_not:n { #2 \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #3 } }
 }


Another solution if you need forwarding of * often is to define an argument processor for it such that #1 will contain a star if a star was given and be empty otherwise:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\ForwardStarProcessor{m}
  {
    \tl_set:Ne \ProcessedArgument { \IfBooleanT{#1}{*} }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\itemJ}{>{\ForwardStarProcessor}s m O{}}
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl
      {
        \task #1 #2 \\ \textit { Solution: } ~ #3
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

